# How to loop over a FormArray inside another formArray

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I can loop over the schedule array to access the dayHeading. I'm not able in the loop to access the daySchedule. I've tried adding a second loop to access the daySchedule with zero success. How would I be able to add a new loop to loop over the daySchedule.

core.js:6162 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'dailySchedule -> 0 -> time'

```js
form = new FormGroup({
schedule : new FormArray([
   new FormGroup({
       dayHeading : new FormControl(''),
       daySchedule : new FormArray([
         new FormGroup({
             time: new FormControl(''),
             name: new FormControl(''),
         }),
       ]),
   }),
])
});
```

```html
   <div 
      *ngFor="let event of form.controls.schedule['controls']; let i = index;"
      [formGroupName]="i">
      <input 
          type="text" 
          formControlName="dayHeading" 
          placeholder="Enter the daily Heading" />

      <input 
          type="text" 
          formControlName="time" 
          placeholder="Enter the event's scheduled time" /> 
      
      <input 
          type="text" 
          formControlName="name" 
          placeholder="Enter the event's name" /> 
  </div>
```

Comment: `dailySchedule` or `daySchedule`?!

Comment: Your code doesn't look clear. what is the 'form' you are trying to iterate? also, you are trying to iterate the schedule array which has dayHeading and day schedule, but not the second form array which contains time and name. so how you get that error? Can you explain what is exactly your issue? Please also reformat a bit your code for better understanding and update this stackblitz according to your error https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forms-formarray-example-ahnzh2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

```
<div formArrayName="schedule">
  <div
    *ngFor="let event of form.get('schedule').controls; let i = index"
    [formGroupName]="i"
  >
    <input
      type="text"
      formControlName="dayHeading"
      placeholder="Enter the daily Heading"
    />
    <div formArrayName="daySchedule">
      <div
        *ngFor="let scheduleEvent of event.get('daySchedule').controls; let j = index"
        [formGroupName]="j"
      >
        <input
          type="text"
          formControlName="time"
          placeholder="Enter the event's scheduled time"
        />

        <input
          type="text"
          formControlName="name"
          placeholder="Enter the event's name"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

A bit gross but bada bing bada boom

Answer (score 0):

Always you want to control a FormArray you need a "getter" to get the formArray. As you has a formArray and inside a FormArray, you need two functions. The first is a "getter", the other one is a simple function with an argument "index"

```
  get scheduleFormArray()
  {
    return this.form.get('schedule') as FormArray
  }
  getDaySchedule(index:number)
  {
    return this.scheduleFormArray.at(index).get('daySchedule') as FormArray
  }
```

The you can use the Donald Duck's "html"

```
<!--here use the getter scheduleFormArray-->
<div *ngFor="let event of scheduleFormArray.controls; let i = index"
  [formGroupName]="i" >
  ....
  <div formArrayName="daySchedule">
    <!--here you use the function getDaySchedule(i)-->
    <div *ngFor="let scheduleEvent of getDaySchedule(i).controls; let j = index"
      [formGroupName]="j">
         ....
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fmuhpx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)