# Nest formArray into other FormArray

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to create a FormArray inside another FormArray but I can't, previously if I was able to do it but it was marking errors right now it no longer marks any errors, but does not believe the fields that I indicate, I hope someone can help me.

In my component I do it as follows

```
formNewProduct = this.formBuilder.group({
    code: ['', Validators.required],
    name: ['', Validators.required],
    infoProduct: this.formBuilder.array([this.newInfo])
  })

  get newInfo(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      size: this.formBuilder.array([this.newSize]),
      description: [''],
      color: [''],
      // stock: [''],
      price: [''],
      image: [''],
    })
  }

  get infos(): FormArray {
    return this.formNewProduct.get('infoProduct') as FormArray;
  }

  addInfos() {
    this.infos.push(this.newInfo);
  }

  removeInfos(i: number) {
    this.infos.controls.splice(i, 1);
    this.infos.updateValueAndValidity();
  }

  get newSize(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      size: [''],
      color: [''],
      stock: [''],
    })
  }

  get sizes(): FormArray {
    return this.newInfo.get('size') as FormArray;
  }

  addSizes() {
    this.sizes.push(this.newSize);
  }

  removeSizes(i: number) {
    this.sizes.controls.splice(i, 1);
    this.sizes.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
```

and my html is this

```
<fieldset formArrayName="infoProduct" class="mb-3">

    <div class="row">

      <fieldset class="col-md-12" name="size" *ngFor="let info of infos.controls; let i = index"
        style="vertical-align: middle" [formGroupName]="i">

        <div formArrayName="size" class="mb-3">

          <fieldset class="col-md-12" name="size" *ngFor="let zise of sizes.controls; let i = index"
            style="vertical-align: middle" [formGroupName]="i">

            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-md-6 form-group">

                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="size" name="size" placeholder="Tamaño"
                  formControlName="size" />

              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">

              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="stock" name="stock" placeholder="Stock"
                formControlName="stock" />

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">

              <a class="genric-btn info-border small" (click)="removeSizes(i)">

                <mdb-icon fas icon="minus-circle"></mdb-icon>Eliminar

              </a>

            </div>

          </fieldset>

          <a class="genric-btn info-border small" (click)="addSizes()">

            <mdb-icon far icon="plus-square"></mdb-icon>Agregar

          </a>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

          <ckeditor [editor]="Editor" [config]="config" data="data" formControlName="description">
          </ckeditor>

          <!-- <textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="description" placeholder="Descripcion"
              cols="30" rows="4" formControlName="description"></textarea> -->

        </div>

        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-md-6 form-group">

            <color-circle formControlName="color"></color-circle>

          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 form-group">

            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="price" name="price" placeholder="Precio"
              formControlName="price" />

          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

          <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image" name="image"
            (change)="cargarImagen($event, i)" />

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

          <a class="genric-btn info-border small" (click)="removeInfos(i)">

            <mdb-icon fas icon="minus-circle"></mdb-icon>Eliminar

          </a>

        </div>

        <hr>

      </fieldset>

    </div>

    <a class="genric-btn info-border small" (click)="addInfos()">

      <mdb-icon far icon="plus-square"></mdb-icon>Agregar

    </a>

  </fieldset>

</div>
```

this don't throw me any error, but doesn't work, hope someone help me to understan how do i need to do it

Comment: you has the same variable "i" in your two llop. You should use two differents, e.g. `let i=index` for the outher and `let j=index` for the inner. futhermore you need iterate over the innerFormArray using a pseudo-getter. See, e.g. this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68105793/how-to-loop-over-a-formarray-inside-another-formarray/68127122#68127122)

Comment: @Eliseo so my code is correct i just need to change my index name?

Comment: No, see when you iterating over size: `let zise of sizes.controls;` sizes has no relation with your formNewProduct, you should has a function `getSizes(index){ return this.infos.at(index).get('sizes') as FormArray}` and iterating over `let zise of getSizes(i).controls); let j=index`

Comment: @Eliseo Thanks i fix the problem